# Python using variable outside of a function (and class)

Tags: python, pyqt5

i am using PyQt5 to open a browser to get a folder and assign it to a variable `folder_path`, if i print it inside the function it works:

```
def browse_folder(self):
        global folder_path
        options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ReadOnly
        folder_path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, "Select Folder", options=options)
        if folder_path:
            global folder_path
            self.folder_line_edit.setText(folder_path)

            self.folder_path = folder_path
            print(folder_path + 'dddwdadds')
            return folder_path
```

the `return` and the `global` is my try to use the variable outside the function and class so when i press submit the windows is gone and the code continues so i can use the variable, i have tried everything.
the last part of the code is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MyApp()
    main_window.show()

    # Tamanho da window
    main_window.setGeometry(400, 400, 400, 200)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
   

# i cannot get this to print
print(folder_path + 'ddd')
```

Full code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

import sys

global folder_path


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Creator")

        # Create a central widget for the main window
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        # Create a grid layout for the central widget
        self.grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)

        ......

        self.submit_button.clicked.connect(self.submit_button_clicked)
        self.exit_button.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.QApplication.quit)
  

       def browse_folder(self):
        global folder_path
        options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ReadOnly
        folder_path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, "Select Folder", options=options)
        if folder_path:
            global folder_path
            self.folder_line_edit.setText(folder_path)

            self.folder_path = folder_path
            print(folder_path + 'dddwdadds')
            return folder_path

    def browse_file(self):
        global file_path
        options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ReadOnly
        file_path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, "Select File", options=options)
        if file_path:
            self.file_line_edit.setText(file_path)
            self.file_path = file_path
            return file_path

    def submit_button_clicked(self):

        QtWidgets.QApplication.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MyApp()
    main_window.show()

    # Tamanho da window
    main_window.setGeometry(400, 400, 400, 200)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    

print(folder_path + 'ddd')
```

Comment: You're never even calling your `browse_folder` method. You don't need a global variable. You're already returning `folder_path`, just call your  function, and store the result: `folder_path = something.browse_folder(); print(older_path + 'ddd')`. IDK what class your `browse_folder` method is defined on, so I can't tell what `something` should be

Comment: the full code: https://pastecode.io/s/bv2fit2v

Comment: Try declaring the `folder_path` variable first outside the function and see if that helps.

Comment: it is in the top

Comment: @Rose You should create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and paste it directly into your question. Imagine how useless this question will be to readers in 10 years if pastecode.io shuts down and that link stops working

Comment: @GautamChettiar Python doesn't have variable declarations. The variable is created when you assign to it.

Comment: It is too big, but i will put it all

Comment: @Rose That's why I said **Minimal**, Reproducible Example. "…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem"

Comment: @Barmar you're right, what I mean was the variable assignment. That will handle the global scope variable declaration on its own.

Comment: @GautamChettiar No it won't. You still have to put `global` in the function, otherwise it will create a local variable and not assign the global variable.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please **read the link** [mre] and **follow the advice** to create a proper example, then [edit] it into the question.

Comment: @Rose You need to read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry @Alexander, i am not of the English language, change it please.

Comment: @Rose You should use a translation tool then. Even if I had the time to help, I don't have a working environment to run and test your code, to be able to minify it for you. It's your job to provide an approachable, easy to follow example that will entice readers to participate and help. You don't have to do it, but it's in your best interest, because if you don't, people just won't spend time on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `file_path` and `folder_path` to be `global` variables you need to define them in the `global` scope prior to trying to assign them values from within a function or class.

I am not entirely sure why you would need to do this but here is an example using the code you provided.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys

folder_path = None  # define variables in global scope
file_path = None


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        ...

    def browse_folder(self):
        global folder_path  # this will work since the variable is already defined
        options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ReadOnly
        path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, "Select Folder", options=options)
        if path:
            self.folder_line_edit.setText(path)
            self.folder_path = path
            print(path + 'dddwdadds')
            folder_path = path   # and this will set the new value

    def browse_file(self):
        global file_path    # file_path was already defined 
        options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ReadOnly
        path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, "Select File", options=options)
        if path:
            self.file_line_edit.setText(path)
            self.file_path = path
            file_path = path   # this will set a new value to file_path

    def submit_button_clicked(self):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MyApp()
    main_window.show()
    # Tamanho da window
    main_window.setGeometry(400, 400, 400, 200)
    app.exec_()   # if you wrap this line with sys.exit() nothing that comes after will execute
    print(folder_path, file_path)  # this line will print the paths chosen once the window exits
```

Comment: In fact that line was the problem: app.exec_()   # if you wrap this line with sys.exit() nothing that comes after will execute. Your answer is correct. thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Does it really have to be in PyQt5 ?

The library "easygui" is really easy to use for simple GUI task like this.

To get a directory, I recommend using [easygui.diropenbox](https://easygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#easygui.diropenbox)

You can simply do :

```
folder_path = easygui.diropenbox("Choose a folder")
```

Comment: I like the feel of the PyQt5 windows style it gives. but i will try it.

Comment: PyQt5 also directly have a dialog for files and directories : https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html